# Mysql Workbench export only data from tables with truncate those tables

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm trying to export data from some tables and add a Truncate statement to those tables I will export using Mysql Workbench, but I don't see where I can add this option, even I have check the advanced options 
but without no luck

In phpmyadmin there is a checkbox called "Truncate table before insert"
Is there something like this in Mysql workbench

Comment: You may opt to dump **both structure and data**. This will add a `DROP IF EXISTS` followed by a `CREATE` statement that clears your existing data from your tables  before inserting the new one.